# How can I get involved with applying my expertise in a specific subject?

Tags: research-process, networking, bioinformatics, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have recently obtained my MS in data science, and am interested in applying it in a few specific fields - urogynecology, microbiome research, and others. I'm still connected to my university as a research fellow but the research options are limited there. How can I find people to work with, and what are the possible scenarios with which I can work with them (i.e. volunteer, employed at a university, employed at a research company, etc)? How do I contact them as well? I feel I have motivation, expertise and a specific purpose but not sure how to connect with the right organization.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you explored internships?

Answer (score 1):

In academia, the best way is to attend research seminars in the fields that interest you and connect with people in there. If there are other universities/institutions in your area, you should start doing that. (Hopefully this will become possible in the Fall, but perhaps zoom options may provide even more opportunities?)

Another (much more expensive) way is to attend professional conferences. Most active researches to that, so you'd be able to make some connections.